# creating a password protected Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

Using Visual Studio 2010 with a C# WPF project. I know how to create an Access 2000-2003 db file using the ADOX namespace.

```
ADOX.CatalogClass cat = new CatalogClass();
string str = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" + _dbPath + ";";
cat.Create(str);
cat = null;
```

Connect and open the database:

```
conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 
       + _dbPath + ";");

//connect to it with a password
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _dbPath + ";User Id=admin;Password=myPassword;"
```

I want to create the file password protected:

```
ADOX.CatalogClass cat = new CatalogClass();
string str = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" 
+ _dbPath + ";Password=myPassword;";
cat.Create(str);
cat = null;
```

This produces an error at runtime:

> Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.

When I create without the password, the database is created successfully.

How can I create a password protected Access database with this strategy?

Comment: Database passwords are not security, but "security theater" -- they are really useless for any practical purpose and should be avoided.

Comment: Theatre can be useful. An Access database password is a nice way to make you think before you tamper.

Comment: I disagree with one exception. If you're using an MDB/ACCDB just to send data to somebody via email, or some other method, a db password is better and stronger than, say, a zip file password. But in a production application with multiple users sharing a back-end data file, it's just bloody stupid to use a database password.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a database password, rather than user level security, which requires a workgroup file, you can change the connection string to include:

```
 Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

That is:

```
ADOX.Catalog cat = new CatalogClass();
string str = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" 
+ _dbPath + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;";
cat.Create(str);
cat = null;
```

-- http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Using the information here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317881, with some minor changes:

```
ADOX._Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();

cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=PW;" +
       "Data Source=C:\\Docs\\NewMDB.mdb;");
```

I find I can create a password protected Access database.

Comment: this is for the connection to the database, it didn`t work for the creation! I get this error that informs me that the database is opened exclusively by another user or that I need permission to view its data. Yet the database is not yet created!!

Comment: I have tried this before, Remou. But it failed!! I think I`ll just encrypt everything in the database or see how to work with the resources ...

Answer (score 1):

Not ADOX (64bit issue) ... but you may find useful this slightly different approach.

```
...
...
using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
using System.Data.OleDb;
...
...

string AccessDB = "C:\users\you\desktop\yourdb.accdb";

oAccess = new Access.Application();
oAccess.NewCurrentDatabase(AccessDB);
oAccess.Quit();

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+AccessDB+".accdb;Mode=12");
con.Open();
// NOTE THE "", '', `` -- that matters 
// NOTE NEW PWD is first THE OLD PWD last
new OleDbCommand(@"ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD `XXxx11` ``", con).ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
con.Dispose();

...
...
// OPEN Later ... and do something
con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + AccessDB + ".accdb;Mode=12;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=XXxx11");
con.Open();
new OleDbCommand(@"CREATE TABLE XYZ ('ID' Number)", con).ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
con.Dispose();
```